# Prevent line break in doc test

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a doc test for a struct member function created by a macro. Apparently it is only possible to use a capture in a standalone doc attribute. However, this forces a line break in the doc test so that the capture fills an entire line in the rendered result. Is this a way to prevent line breaks or to use the capture directly without using procedural macros?

````rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! gen_functions {
    ($name:tt) => {
        /// # Usage
        /// 
        /// ```
        /// let h = 
        #[doc = $name]
        ///  {};
        /// h.test_a();
        /// ```
        pub fn test_a(&self) {
            println!("test a")
        }
    };
}

pub struct CustomStruct {}
impl CustomStruct {
    gen_functions!("CustomStruct");
}

fn main() {
    let h = CustomStruct {};
    h.test_a();
}
````

And the resulting doc test. It does compile but it is difficult to read (compared to the version in the main function):

```rust
let h = 
CustomStruct
{};
h.test_a();
```

Comment: `#[doc(" let h = ", $name, " {};")]` should work I advice you to create issue in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues

Comment: There's a macro crate for this: https://lib.rs/crates/doc-comment

Comment: @Stargateur `#[doc(...)]` doesn't work, the right syntax is `#[doc = ...]` for documentation

Comment: @Aloso As I said "should" work, it doesn't..., https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute.html.

Comment: @Stargateur the syntax with parentheses is used for _configuration_. For instance, `#[doc(hidden)]` means that the item is not displayed in the documentation, and `#[doc(inline)]` will inline items in the docs, when they are re-exported. [More infos](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/the-doc-attribute.html)

Comment: @Aloso I don't care, rustdoc could implement it that what I want to say. for example `#[doc(doc = " let h = ", doc = $name, doc = " {};")]` or something.

Comment: @Stargateur I wrote a post [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/idea-concatenate-strings-in-doc/12042) to pitch your idea (although I proposed a slightly different syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone showed me a nice solution on [this internals thread](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/idea-concatenate-strings-in-doc/12042/3), which uses a macro. I adjusted the macro to make it nicer to use.

Usage:

````rust
macro_rules! gen_functions {
    ($name:tt) => {
        doc! {
            /// # Usage
            ///
            /// ```
            [concat!(" let h = ", $name, " {};")]
            /// h.test_a();
            /// ```
            @ pub fn test_a(&self) {
                println!("test a")
            }
        }
    };
}
````

And this is the macro:

```rust
macro_rules! doc {
    {
        $(#[$m:meta])*
        $(
            [$doc:expr]
            $(#[$n:meta])*
        )*
        @ $thing:item
    } => {
        $(#[$m])*
        $(
            #[doc = $doc]
            $(#[$n])*
        )*
        $thing
    }
}
```

The macro converts strings in `[`square brackets`]` into `#[doc = _]` attributes. What makes it special is that it can contain [concat!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html) and [stringify!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) macro calls. They can also be combined, e.g.

````rust
doc! {
    /// # Usage
    ///
    /// ```
    [concat!(" let ", stringify!(h), " = ", stringify!(CustomStruct), " {};")]
    /// h.test_a();
    /// ```
    @ pub fn test_a(&self) {
        println!("test a")
    }
}
````

Comment: This works good for module level functions. If I try it inside of a `impl` block I get  a strange error message `expected one of 'async', 'const', 'crate', 'default', 'extern', 'fn', 'pub', 'type', or 'unsafe', found 'pub fn test_a(self: (/*ERROR*/)) { println!("test a") }'` (removing the self parameter does not solve this error, origin is the `doc` macro). It seems it does not parse the the `$thing:item` capture properly. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You have to put an `@` before the item (this was necessary so the syntax of the macro is unambiguous).

Comment: I did that. The code I used for testing: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/pixix4/33658477f67a3a46c2069acff9c49270)